# How to use R language to determine whether a line is the same character

Tags: r

I have a data.frame like the following：

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1 a  a  b  a  a
2 a  a  a 
3 b  b  b  b
4 a  c  d
```

I want to keep the lines with the same character in one line (in my example, lines 2 and 3), is there any function that can help me achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `apply`

```r
df[apply(df, 1, function(x) length(unique(x[x != ''])) == 1), ]
#V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#2  a  a  a      
#3  b  b  b  b
```

Explanation: `length(unique(x[x != '')) == 1` checks if non-empty elements of a vector `x` contain only a single unique element. `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` means that we loop through the rows of the `data.frame`.

---

### Sample data

```r
df <- read.table(text = "  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1 a  a  b  a  a
2 a  a  a  '' ''
3 b  b  b  b ''
4 a  c  d '' ''", header = T)
```